# option to get the current working directory

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm using oh-my-zsh and wanted to write a small plugin which would executes command autoamtically when i switch directories. So for example I will have to some kind of mapping like

/Users/ed1t/Dropbox="echo Entering Dropbox Directory"

I could write a function cd() to do this but is that the efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`chpwd` hook function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions).

```
chpwd () {
  echo "Changing directory from $OLDPWD to $PWD"
}
```